# Download blob from Azure storage with powershell -> LoaderException

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I use powershell to download a blob from blobstorage in an Azure startup task. I updated Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage library today from 3.0.3.0 to 4.0.1.0 via NuGet.

After the library update files are still downloaded correctly but I get same sort of warning in command window:

'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.'

```
function download_from_storage ($container, $blob, $connection, $destination) {
    Add-Type -Path ((Get-Location).Path + '\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll')
    $storageAccount = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount]::Parse($connection)
    $blobClient = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient($storageAccount.BlobEndpoint, $storageAccount.Credentials)   
    $container = $blobClient.GetContainerReference($container)
    $remoteBlob = $container.GetBlockBlobReference($blob)
    $remoteBlob.DownloadToFile($destination + "\" + $blob, [System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate)
}

$connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<AcountName>;AccountKey=<Accountkey>'

# JRE
$jre = 'jre-7u60-windows-x64.exe'
$node = 'node-v0.10.29-x64.msi'
download_from_storage 'java-runtime' $jre $connection_string (Get-Location).Path
download_from_storage 'nodejs' $node $connection_string (Get-Location).Path
```

Since it is still working I am just clueless why the message occurs in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer to your question but here is a much simpler way of downloading files from blob storage:

```
$dlPath = "C:\temp\"
$container = "BlobContainer"
Set-AzureSubscription "NameOfYourSubscription" -CurrentStorageAccount "storageAccountName"
Get-AzureStorageContainer $container | Get-AzureStorageBlob | 
    Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Destination $container
```

Comment: There is no azure powershell in a fresh WorkerRole instance. Therefore I went with the Add-Type cmdlet. But you are right with Azure powershell available this would be more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by installing Azure PowerShell itself in the startup task and then execute the download Azure blob cmdlet. Here are rouphly the steps

Installing Azure PowerShell automatically

- Create new service project (New-AzureServiceProject)
- Execute Add-AzureWebRole
- Change the cscfg to use osFamily=3 (to use new PS version which is compatible with Azure PS)
- Copy Azure PowerShell MSI under WebRole1\bin directory
- Edit WebRole1\startup.cmd to include this line msiexec /i AzurePowerShell.msi /quiet

Authenticating Azure PowerShell so it can execute cmdlets (if you want to use storage cmdlets only you can ignore this step and pass your storage key/name when executing the Get-AzureStorageBlobContent cmdlet)

- Copy a latest publish settings file (myPublishSettings.publishsettings) inside WebRole1\bin folder
- Edit WebRole1\startup.cmd to include this line after the one added before: PowerShell.exe –Command “Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile .\myPublishSettings.publishsettings)